# Adding buttons in a chart using plotly in R for annotation

Tags: r, button, plotly, bar-chart

I am working with plotly buttons in R. I am trying to set up some buttons to turn annotations on or off on a plot but can't get it to work. Below is my code.

```
plotAllCycle<- plot_ly(


 data,
  x = ~Date,
  y = ~Quantity,
  name = ~Cycle,
  type = "bar"
) %>% layout(
  title = "Whop",
  barmode = "stack",
  xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date"))
)

 

annotation1<- list(
  x = ~Date,
  y = unlist(tapply(data$Quantity, data$Date, FUN=cumsum))-(data$Quantity/2),
  text = ~Quantity,
  showarrow = FALSE,
  font = list(
    color = "white"
  )
)

 

annotation2<- list(
  data = data %>% select(Date, Totals) %>% unique(),
  x = ~Date,
  y = ~Totals,
  text = ~Totals,
  showarrow = TRUE
)

 

updatemenus<- list(
  list(
    active = -1,
    type = "buttons",
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = "Totals",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(title = "Total Products Made",
                         annotations = list(c(), annotation2)))),
      list(
        label = "Per Product",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(title = "Total Per Product",
                         annotations = list(annotation1, c() )))),
      list(
        label = "Both",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(title = "Product Totals",
                         annotations = list(annotation1, annotation2)))),
      list(
        label = "None",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(title = "Total Per Product",
                         annotations = list(c(), c() ))))
    )
  )
)

 

plotAllCycle<- plotAllCycle %>% layout(updatemenus = updatemenus)
```

I have been able to use the buttons to change titles and change which bars i see in the plot but i cannot make the buttons change the annotations

[This is chart where I want to on/off annotations with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoYpE.jpg)